# Lane Changing in SUMO

Tags: sumo

Is it possible to make a vehicle inside SUMO environment which is inserted on a specific lane to shift to other lane in a certain time period from one lane to the other?
Can this be done without using TraCI and is there any particular syntax format to do so?

Answer (score 0):

No, without TraCI this is currently not possible. You could specify a stop on the target lane but this wouldn't be time triggered change but rather location triggered and furthermore the vehicle would stop there (or at least decelerate) and this probably not what you want.